# How to modify the contact sheet in nuke using Python?

Tags: python, nuke

I am trying to create contact sheet in Nuke using Python script which is as follows :

```
def create_contact_sheet(self,entities, version_paths, first_frame,last_frame):
    movie_per_sheet = 30

    print ("no of movies per sheet:", movie_per_sheet)
    shot_list_splits = [entities[i:i + movie_per_sheet] for i in range(0, len(entities), movie_per_sheet)]
    print ("no of required sheets:", len(shot_list_splits))

    print("entities", entities)
    print("shot version split", version_paths)
    last_batch_rnode_pos = 0
    first_rnode_xpos = None
    r_node_xpos = None

    print('version map', version_paths)
    for sht_index, e_sht_list in enumerate(shot_list_splits):
        nodes_for_backdrop = []
        # create contact sheet:
        ctt_sheet = nuke.createNode("ContactSheet", "sheet_%s" %(sht_index + 1))
        print (">>> create ctt_sheet",ctt_sheet.name())
        nodes_for_backdrop.append(ctt_sheet)
        ctt_sheet["rows"].setValue(5)
        ctt_sheet["columns"].setValue(6)
        ctt_sheet["width"].setValue(5 * 1920)
        ctt_sheet["height"].setValue(6 * 1080)

        ctt_sheet.setSelected(False)

        for index, e_shot in enumerate(e_sht_list):
            exr_path = version_paths[e_shot][0]
            if exr_path == None:
                exr_r_node = nuke.createNode("Constant")
            else:
                exr_r_node = nuke.createNode("Read", "name %s file %s" % (e_shot, exr_path))
            nodes_for_backdrop.append(exr_r_node)
            r_node_xpos = last_batch_rnode_pos + index * 100
            exr_r_node["xpos"].setValue(r_node_xpos)
            exr_r_node["ypos"].setValue(0)
            exr_r_node['first'].setValue(first_frame)
            exr_r_node['last'].setValue(last_frame)
            ctt_sheet.setInput(index, exr_r_node)
            exr_r_node.setSelected(False)
            # store first node xpos to place ctt_sheet_xpos
            if index == 0:
                first_rnode_xpos = r_node_xpos

        # fix ctt_sheet_xpos
        ctt_sheet_xpos = (len(e_sht_list) * 100) / 2 + first_rnode_xpos
        ctt_sheet["xpos"].setValue(ctt_sheet_xpos)
        ctt_sheet["ypos"].setValue(300)

        last_batch_rnode_pos = r_node_xpos + 200
        self.create_back_drop(nodes_for_backdrop, ctt_sheet)

def create_back_drop(self, nodes, ctt_sheet):
    """
    make sure nodes were selected before execution this function
    """
    # select nodes
    for e_node in nodes:
        e_node.setSelected(True)

    node = nukescripts.autoBackdrop()
    node["label"].setValue(ctt_sheet.name())

    # de-select nodes
    for e_node in nodes:
        e_node.setSelected(False)
```

**Here I am doing following operations:**

**1)** First creating split batches of 30 sheets so all nodes are easily readable.
**2)** Iterating over the list of `entities ['a0','a1','a2']` and using the dictionary `version_map = {'a0':[exr_path, hud_path], 'a1' :[None, hud_path], 'a2':[exr_path, None]}`, to extract necessary information.
**3)** Then I am creating contact sheet for each element in entities I am creating a read node by extracting exr_path from the dictionary, which is giving me output something like this

[image]

(I am creating constant nodes if the paths aren't there)

**What I am trying to achieve ?**

rather than creating read nodes of exr and directly map them , I want to create two read nodes one for exr and other for hud as well and create a merge_node to overlap them with each other.
something like this

[image]

**Issue i am facing**

I am not able to create a worflow to create another node for huds and then map the merge node rather than the exr_read_node itself.

I tried few thing but it just gave me distorted output of nodes all over the graph.

This might be easy but as it is my first Nuke tool i am not able to figure it out,any help would be really great.

**Thanks & Regards**

Answer (score 0):

Update :

I was able to achieve this using the following method

```
def get_merge_node(self, e_shot ,source_paths, first_frame, last_frame,xpos, ypos):

    exr_path = source_paths[0]
    hud_path = source_paths[1]
    if exr_path is not None:
        exr_node = nuke.createNode("Read", "name %s" % (e_shot))
        exr_node["file"].setValue(exr_path)
        exr_node['first'].setValue(first_frame)
        exr_node['last'].setValue(last_frame)
    else:
        exr_node = nuke.createNode("Constant")

    if hud_path is not None:
        hud_node = nuke.createNode("Read", "name %s" % (e_shot))
        hud_node["file"].setValue(hud_path)
        hud_node['first'].setValue(first_frame)
        hud_node['last'].setValue(last_frame)
    else:
        hud_node = nuke.createNode("Constant")

    merge_node = nuke.createNode("Merge", "name %s" % (e_shot))

    exr_node["xpos"].setValue(xpos)
    exr_node["ypos"].setValue(ypos - 200)

    hud_node["xpos"].setValue(xpos)
    hud_node["ypos"].setValue(ypos - 100)

    merge_node.setInput(1, hud_node)
    merge_node.setInput(0, exr_node)
    merge_node["mix"].setValue(0.5)
    return merge_node
```

I created a separate method for this node creation and linking , then I am returning the merge node here and using that in Contact Sheet.